# Excel VBA TopLeftCell property

Tags: vba, excel, properties, shapes

I want to get .TopLeftCell property of each Shape Object in Selection.ShapeRange, but I got runtime error 438 saying 'this object does not support this property or method' when I run following code.

```
Sub testTopLeftCell()
    For Each target In Selection.ShapeRange
        MsgBox target.TopLeftCell.Address
    Next
End Sub
```

However, following code works.

```
Sub testTopLeftCell2()
    For Each target In Selection.ShapeRange
        MsgBox ActiveSheet.Shapes(target.Name).TopLeftCell.Address
    Next
End Sub
```

Could anyone teach me, what are the problems in the first code and why the second code works. I got really confused with this problem.

Comment: Shapes(eg. one or more Rectangles, Pictures, Ovals...) are in the `Selection`. I'm sure the second code works, but the first code does not when I run the code after selecting shapes. There are similar question on [another website](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/432495-vbulletin-macro-problem-using-topleftcell.html#), but not fully answered. Just for info, my current environment is MS Excel 2007. Thanks anyway.

Comment: maybe use option explicit, and declare target : Dim target as shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`For Each` for ShapeRange Collection does not offer the access to `ShapeRange(i)`, so `target` in the first code is an instance of ShapeRange object(reffering same Object reffered by ShapeRange(i), but is not a Shape object.)

According to reference articles on MSDN, [ShapeRange Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194815%28v=office.15%29.aspx) does not have the .TopLeftCell property.

On the other hand, `ShapeRange(i)` means `ShapeRange.Item(i)` which returns single [Shape Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193908%28v=office.15%29.aspx) with .TopLeftCell property. Of course, we also can access Shape Object as a member of Shapes Collection by `Shapes(j)`.

So, we can think the ShapeRange Object as a kind of interfaces for the Shapes Object, which offers properties slightly different from those Shape Object has(in this case ShapeRange does not have .TopLeftCell property but Shape has.)

In other cases ShapeRange offers same properties as Shape Object does.

This is why confusions come up with following code which returns same result 3 times, when single Shape Object is selected. But these result comes up, simply because .Name property and TypeName Function returns same result for ShapeRange Object and Shape Object.

```
Sub testShapeRange()
    For Each target In Selection.ShapeRange
        MsgBox "target: " + target.Name + "," + TypeName(target)
        MsgBox "Selection.ShapeRange(1): " + _
            Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name + ", " + _
            TypeName(Selection.ShapeRange(1))
        MsgBox "ActiveSheet.Shapes(target.Name): " + _
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(target.Name).Name + "," + _
            TypeName(ActiveSheet.Shapes(target.Name))
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because in these subs **target** is a ShapeRange.  A ShapeRange does not have a TopLeftCell property.  It does have a Name property...........this is why the second sub works.

Here is a way to get individual Shapes from a ShapeRange:

```
Sub durall()
    Dim s As Shape, i As Long
    For i = 1 To Selection.ShapeRange.Count
        Set s = Selection.ShapeRange(i)
        MsgBox s.Name
        MsgBox s.TopLeftCell.Address
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped me out finding answer for this question.